# Prove that the symmetry group of the circle is $O(2, \mathbb{R})$. What is its order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, circles, isometry

Q:Prove that the symmetry group of the circle is $O(2, \mathbb{R})$. What is its order?

I'm confused about this question. 
Here is what I have thought: I need to figure out a matrix that can represent the circle, and proving that this matrix is sufficient to the condition of $O(2, \mathbb{R})$. Is this right? But I don't know how to get the matrix.
Any hint for this? Thank you!

Comment: A matrix that represents the circle? The circle is given by the usual equation $x^2+y^2=1$. Matrices are going to act on the vectors $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Is my thinking right?

Comment: @S.Ga How does a matrix represent a circle?

Comment: Not as you said it, no. That's why I restated things for you.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I still don't have idea to solve this.

Comment: You're looking for an invertible linear transformations that preserve the lengths of the vectors. What does that tell you about the area of the rhombus defined by the image of the unit square in the canonical basis vectors? In particular consider its diagonals and see if you can puzzle out why their lengths matter in the area calculation and how that relates to determinants.

Answer (score 0):

If $M\in O(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $v\in S^1$, then $M.v\in S^1$. Furthermore, if $w\in S^1$, then $\bigl\|M.w-M.v\bigr\|=\|v-w\|$. Therefore, every element of $O(2,\mathbb{R})$ is an isometry of $S^1$. On the other hand, every isometry of $S^1$ is of this type.

Of course, $O(2,\mathbb{R})$ is an infinite group, since it contains all matrices for the type$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$($\theta\in\mathbb R$).